# "React Axios POST Request to Express API Returns 404 Not Found"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm currently working on a React project that communicates with an Express.js API. I'm using Axios to make API requests. My goal is to create a new "Prestation" and associate it with a specific user ID when the user submits a form in the React app.

However, I'm encountering a "404 Not Found" error when I attempt to make a POST request to the endpoint /api/prestation/${id}. I've already verified that the user ID (id) is being captured correctly from the route parameters using useParams().

Here's the relevant part of my React component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import myApi from "../api/service";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import "./../styles/PrestationForm.css";

function PrestationForm() {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [price = 0, setPrice] = useState(0);

    const params = useParams();
    const id = params.id;
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const response = await myApi.post("/api/prestation/${id}", {
                title,
                description,
                price,
            });
            console.log("Prestation created:", response.data);
            // Réinitialisez les champs du formulaire après la création
            setTitle("");
            setDescription("");
            setPrice(0);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error creating prestation:", error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="form-createAPrestation">
            <h2>Create a New Prestation</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label>Title:</label>
                    <input type="text" value={title} onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Description:</label>
                    <textarea value={description} onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Price:</label>
                    <input type="number" value={price} onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)} />
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Create</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PrestationForm;
```

On the server side, I have an Express route that should handle the POST request:

```
const router = require("express").Router();

// ... Other middleware imports and setup ...

router.post("/:prestationId", isAuthenticated, isAdmin, async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        // ... Logic to create a new prestation ...
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});

module.exports = router;

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

I've ensured that the route parameters are being passed correctly and that the authentication middleware is working as expected. However, I'm still getting the "404 Not Found" error. I've tried debugging by logging the id and checking the network request in the browser's developer tools, but I'm unable to pinpoint the issue.

Could someone please provide guidance on what might be causing this error and how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much indeed.

Conrad